# Why "den Studierenden"

Tags: grammatical-case, gender, grammaticality, declension

Could someone possibly explain why it is "Den Studierenden" in the following sentence:

> Ziel des Studienganges ist es, den Studierenden den Zugang zu linguistischer Forschung internationalen Niveaus zu ermöglichen.

Answer (score 4):

Because it's a dative (...to make it possible **to the students**...)